# Why does `docker build` sometimes not do anything and how can I force it to always build

Tags: docker

I'm doing go development.
Sometimes when I do `docker build` it doesn't build. It's pretty obvious by the output, since the build process has to download some libs into the container.
What can I put in my Dockerfile to force it to always build?
This is one of the Dockerfiles that does this sometimes, with some minor employer stuff sanitized:

```
FROM golang:1.17 AS build

WORKDIR /software

COPY . ./

# Without this, the resultant binary expects some DNS resolver
# files that are actually optional, and (obviously) don't
# exist on scratch
ENV CGO_ENABLED=0

RUN go build

FROM scratch

COPY --from=build /program /program

EXPOSE 8000/tcp

ENTRYPOINT [ "/program" ]
```

Comment: Your question is likely to be closed as the way it's phrased it's basically a vent. Can you give details of what you are after, what you did and what happens please?

Comment: @PreetSangha updated the question with an example.

Comment: I'm still seeing this problem and don't have a solution. Based on the docs, it should recognize that the go source files have changed and stop using the cache, yet it happens all the time. Is there an option to add debug output such that I can better narrow down what's happening?

Answer (score 2):

Docker build will only re-build where there is a change in your Dockerfile.

It will cache what it has built that has not changed so it does not have to do it again later.

You can use `--no-cache` to force this, but I wouldn't do this every build as just wastes time, effort, and computing power.

---

Here are the official docs to this feature: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#leverage-build-cache

Comment: Based on the document you linked to, I shouldn't be having this problem as the `COPY` should notice that some files have changed and invalidate the cache for all subsequent steps. (i.e. I shouldn't need `--no-cache`) I wish I could figure out a pattern to when this happens.

Comment: I suspect you're probably doing something wrong.  If you have a COPY that copies new files (ones that are different in any way from a previous build) it will not cache the layers beyond that statement.  Can you share your dockerfile or more information?

Comment: @Alex updated the question with an example.

Comment: Great. Will have a look tomorrow and see what I can come up with. No doubt someone else will look before me =)

Answer (score 1):

can use
`docker build --no-cache`